# Is this QEC scheme technology dependant?

Tags: experimental-realization

Is this [1] type of error correction also usable for **ion-trap** based quantum computers?
Is it quantum technology dependent?

[1] P. Das et al., “A Scalable Decoder Micro-architecture for Fault-Tolerant Quantum Computing,” pp. 1–19, 2020. arXiv:2001.06598v1 [online available](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.06598)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please add more details? Bear in mind that nobody will read whole article. Please provide necessary details in you question.